# Can using eval to dynamically build an associative array be made secure?

Tags: bash, eval, associative-array

I know that using `eval` to execute user-input strings is dangerous. [From another question,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94749/why-does-this-syntax-not-work-for-declaring-associative-array) and tests so far, it seems that the only way to dynamically initialize an associate array is to use eval.

Considering the following example (say `hash_test.sh`), it is clear that user input could be used to inject and run arbitrary commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

key0="a"
value0="b"
key1='c]="d"); echo "You were hacked on $(date)"; #'
value2="2"
input=$(cat - <<EOF
[$key0]="$value0"
[$key1]="$value1"
EOF
)

eval "declare -A hash=( ${input[@]} )"
echo "keys";
for key in "${!hash[@]}"; do
    echo "Key: $key Value: ${hash[$key]}";
done;
```

Running `hash_test.sh` demonstrates the problem.

Is there a technique that could safely escape the user input to make this secure?

Comment: Point taken about using harmless commands @jm666. I was attempting to demonstrate why the use of `eval` was a particular concern, and tried to ensure safety by giving the example three commands (so the file would be created then deleted). Nevertheless, I agree that I could have been more creative and will improve the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First -- the `eval` given in the linked answer was redundant with behavior of `declare` without it:

```
string='["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value2"'
declare -A assoc_array="($string)"
echo "Value of key1 is ${assoc_array[key1]}"
```

However, this *does* have the same security risks:

```
string='["key1"]="$(touch /tmp/i-am-insecure)"'
declare -A assoc_array="($string)"
ls -l /tmp/i-am-insecure ## guess what, it exists
```

You *could* quote the values being generated by `printf %q`, if you really insisted:

```
printf -v string '[%q]=%q' "key1" '$(touch /tmp/i-am-insecure)'
declare -A assoc_array="($string)"
ls -l /tmp/i-am-insecure ## not found!
```

---

But best-practice is to iteratively populate your array. To serialize in an entirely unambiguous format:

```
for key in "${!array[@]}"; do printf '%s\0' "$key" "${array[$key]}"; done >file
```

...and to deserialize from that format:

```
declare -A array
while IFS= read -r -d '' key && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do array[$key]=$value; done <file
```

Comment: I'm not clear on *what* you mean to indicate you had tried -- if that's in reference to iteratively populating the array, I've amended an example of a way to do that that's entirely in line with best practices.

Comment: It seems I saved an incomplete comment. I'm not sure what I was trying to say anymore. Thanks for the extended example regardless. I'll give it a try and then accept the answer.